# Using one report field with two filters

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am making a report and I faced with an issue.

When I wanted to pick Ageing category with my marco and put it for two categories for some reason it does not work. Excel thinks using the recorded macro, that I want to change the filter for Ageing category, not to use it for two filters, for rows and values.

I share my macro below:

Sheets("AL").Select

```
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "AL!A1:AF" & lr, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "AL_2!R3C1", TableName:="Kimutatás2", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("AL_2").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2").PivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2").PivotFields("Cust descr")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2").PivotFields("Ageing category")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Kimutatás2").PivotFields("Ageing category"), "Mennyiség / Ageing category", _
    xlCount
Range("A1").Select
```

Do you have any idea what I do wrong?

I think the issue is somewhere here:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2").PivotFields("Ageing category")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Kimutatás2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Kimutatás2").PivotFields("Ageing category"), "Mennyiség / Ageing category", _
    xlCount
```

Please see a picture attached.

Thanks in advance!

What I want to do is to have Ageing category at Rows and Values as well
[image: What I want to do is to have Ageing category at Rows and Values as well]